# Store PrivateKey in ServletContext

Tags: java, private-key, servlets

I would like your opinion. I am developing a `Servlet` that has to **sign** the requests that it sends to an endpoint.

In order to avoid read from file the server's keystore, load it and get the private key, I am doing all of that in a listener that implements `ServletContextListener`. In this way this is done only when the servlet is initialised (deployed).

Once I get the private key I am storing it in the application's `ServletContext`. Do you think that is a good design decision?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever solution you choose, you'll have the private key in memory at some time. So any cracker having access to the memory could find a way to get this private key. Loading it once and storing it in memory at startup looks like a good solution to me. Just make sure that the server is not easily accessible to malicious persons.

Comment: Or you could just read it during the servlet init and store it directly in the servlet.  No need to have a Listener.  Just simpler, but same security implications as mentioned by JB.

Comment: Thanks JB! I am agree. It is supposed that the server is not going to be visible from "outside".

Comment: Andres, you are right, but I prefer execute the loading key code just when the application is deployed. Thanks!